# Is it possible to print the data from a text file to a html page via javascript or python(Flask)?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm getting my head around python and running it off a server (in this case Flask). Basically Im trying to print some contents of a local text file to a html page. I take in a few input values from the user (a name, email and comment) and I'm store these to a local text file line by line. At the moment I can get the latest input to print on the page (i.e the comment, and the name and email of the user) but it gets replaced everytime the form is re-submitted. I'm kind of just messing around with it at the moment (for example I read and print 5 instances of the user input from the file to the server). However I'm trying to print the name, email and comments on to the form_action.html page and keep all the previous comments along with it. As I said I can print the contents, and they show up in the cmd prompt, however could this be done via javascript perhaps so it displays on the html page, or could it be done using a different way using python. The book I'm using doesn't cover how to do it and I can't find anything online. Anyone able to cure my curiosity? If I'm not making sense please ask me and I'll be happy to elaborate. Cheers!

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Define a route for the default URL, which loads the form
@app.route('/')
def form():
return render_template('form_submit.html')

# Define a route for the action of the form, for example '/hello/'
# We are also defining which type of requests this route is 
# accepting: POST requests in this case
@app.route('/hello/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
  name=request.form['yourname']
  email=request.form['youremail']
  comment=request.form['yourcomment']


  f = open ("user+comments.txt","a")

  f.write(name)
  f.write(' ')
  f.write(email)
  f.write(' ')
  f.write(comment)
  f.write('\n')

  f.close()

  #This reads the first 5 lines and prints them to the cmd prompt
  with open("user+comments.txt") as f:
      i = 1
      for x in range (0,5):
        lines = f.readlines(i)
        print(lines)
        i+=1
        x+=1
     f.close()




 return render_template('form_action.html', name=name, email=email,   
 comment=comment)

 # Run the app :)
 if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

**form_submit.html**

```
  // This page takes in the initial information via the text boxes and     
     passes the information to the python file above

 <html>
 <body style="background-color: #3DC247;">

 <head>
 <title>Python</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div align = "center">
  <h1 style="font-family:verdana;">PYTHON PAGE</h1>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h3 style="font-family:verdana;">Please fill in your details    
  below and your comment to join the discussion</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('hello') }}">
              <label for="yourname" style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
  enter your name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br /><br>
              
              <label for="youremail" style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
  enter your email:</label>
              <input type="text" name="youremail" /><br /><br>
              
              <label for="yourcomment"style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
  enter your comment:</label>
              <input type="textarea" name="yourcomment" rows="4" cols="50">    
  <br>
              <input type="submit" /><br>
            </form>
        </div>
        
  </body>
  </html>
```

**form_action.html**

```
 // I'm trying to get the information to pass to this page. The text boxes     
    from the previous html page remain on this html page as I want to               
    continue to add comments without having to go back to form_submit.html    
    each time

  <html>

  <body style="background-color: #3DC247;">

  <head>
  <title>Python</title>
   </head>

   <div align = "center">

   <h1 style="font-family:verdana;">PYTHON PAGE</h1>


   <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h3 style="font-family:verdana;">Please fill in your details 
   below and your comment to join the discussion</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('hello') }}">
              <label for="yourname" style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
    enter your name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br /><br>
              
              <label for="youremail" style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
    enter your email:</label>
              <input type="text" name="youremail" /><br /><br>
              
              <label for="yourcomment"style="font-family:verdana;">Please  
    enter your comment:</label>
              <input type="textarea" name="yourcomment" rows="4" cols="50">    
    <br>
              <input type="submit" /><br>
            </form>
    // I included this bit as an original attempt to post a single comment    
       to the page(it will display while still passing the info to the text  
       file via python)
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="title">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <strong>{{name}} ({{email}}):</strong><br>
            {{comment}}
        </div> 
        </div>
      </body>   
   </html>
```

Comment: What is the point of this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Essentially what Im trying to achieve is to be able to display a number of comments on a web page based on what the user has input into the textfields(name, email,comment), something similar to a very basic forum of sorts. So basically, for example, after joe bloggs inputs his details; "Joe Bloggs (jbloggs@gmail.com) I Love Python", will be displayed. Next Jane Doe could come along and add a comment which would read; "Jane Doe (jdoe@gmail.com) I Also Love Python", will display. Does this make a little bit more sense?

Comment: as usualy if you need more than one element then you have to create list with elements. And then send this list to template and use template `for` function to display elements from this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are reading and writing to file ok, but in the template you are getting only the last name or entry, since you are not storing what was read from the file in a list.
Try something in a way of this:

```
f = open("user+comments.txt", "a")

f.write(name + ':' + email + ':' + comment)
f.write('\n')
f.close()

details = []
# This reads the the first 5 lines and prints them to the cmd prompt
with open("user+comments.txt") as f:
    i = 1
    for x in range(0, 5):
        lines = f.readlines(i)
        print(lines)
        i += 1
        x += 1
        try:
            details.append(lines[0].split(':'))
        except:
            'List cannot be populated'
f.close()

return render_template('form_action.html', details=details) # return details list containing user, email, comment
```

I have added ':' as a splitter between name, email and comment, so it's easier to split entries

'Details' returned now contain everything needed for the template.

But inside the template, you'll need a loop as well, in Flask it's something like:

```
{% for user, email, comment in details %}
                        User: {{ user }} <br/>
                        Email: {{ email }} <br/>
                        Comment: {{ comment }} <br/>
                    {% endfor %}
```

[and the screenshot from your html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqC9F.jpg)

You'll need to reverse the entries as well, so you can display last 5,
hope it helps!

Comment: Thats definitely what I'm looking for Thank You! Any idea why it might result in the following error though : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: Try 'unpacking' only one and see what it is, so instead of name, email, commment use only name for the loop.     This error happens when you ask for more elements from the list than they actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

In your GET route "("/")" You would need to read all the comments from the file, then do a render_template and pass these to the form_submit template.

In the form_submit template you would then loop through these comments and render the html for each of them in that loop.

I'm not that familiar with how flask does things but this seems to be the most logical way in a templated web app.

There is no need for two templates here, actually. In the POST route ('/hello') you should redirect it back to root "("/")" and let that handle the rendering again.

Additionally, I would recommend not having to different routes for, essentially, the same resource. "/" Could accept BOTH the initial GET, and then the POST. But only do this at the end...